# How do i resolve this : javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Resource_not_found

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I was trying to get familier with JAX-RS and here is my code sniplets

```
WebTarget target; // this object reference was created successfully 

 public Client[] getClients() {
        return target.request().get(Client[].class); // NOTE target is not null
}
```

This is the exception which is logged

```
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Resource_not_found
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:945)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:784)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$500(JerseyInvocation.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:672)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:668)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:397)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:297)
    at org.business.bee.client.ClientBean.getClients(ClientBean.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

If an error is thrown in a getter you'll get the _"FATAL: JSF1073: javax.el.ELException caught during processing of RENDER_RESPONSE 6"_ or similar. The underlying (real!) error has nothing to do with jsf, ejb, jstl or facelets. Just make sure the following exception (thrown in **your code** trying to access a rest service) does not happen:

```
  javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Resource_not_found
```